# How to understand "Here you are." "You are here" or "Here are you"?

Tags: difference

When we want to give something to somebody, we may say:

> Here you are.

But I don't understand why this sentence means "I give it to you".

What are the differences among them:

- Here you are.
- Here are you.
- You are here.

Comment: Also: *Here you go!*

Comment: Opposite to that but equally interesting - *There you are!*

Comment: @MaulikV Interestingly enough, "There you are!" can either mean the opposite or the exact same thing! Sometimes "There you are"/"There you go" are used to mean the same thing as "Here you are"/"Here you go". And other times they are used in the way you suggest; to mean "Oh look! Finally I've found you!". So yes, that was a very interesting point for you to mention!

Answer (score 2):

**Here you are** / **There you are**: is *commonly* used when you're looking for someone (or something) and you found them. For example: you're looking for your brother in the house, and when you found him, you said: there you are!

I've never heard of **here are you**, but I don't think that's a phrase.

**You are here** is used when you're basically telling someone that they are... here. You can pretty much replace the word *here* with any other places.

**Here you go** is pretty much used when you're giving someone something. Do note that **here you are** and **here you go** are interchangeable, but the common usage of **here you are** is in my first example.

Comment: What 'Here you are/go' means when giving something is what the OP asked.

Answer (score 2):

I have a hypothesis that "here you are" -- which is entirely idiomatic English, but grammatically bizarre -- is a contracted form of "here, you are served", in which "here" doesn't refer to "you" but to the thing which you are served.  But that's just a hypothesis; as used idiomatically, it makes no obvious literal sense.

"Here are you" is barely grammatical, but not at all idiomatic.

"You are here" is both grammatical and idiomatic, and can be taken literally, "you are present in this place."  It can be used as an exclamation of surprise, "You are here!  I didn't hear you come in." or a statement informing the addressed party that they have reached a location, as when talking them through travel, via a cell phone.  "Where are you?  Can you see the gas station?  Oh, then you're right outside my building.  You are here."

Answer (score 0):

**Here you are** may be **You are here** but the emphasis is on **here**.
Same thing for **There you are**.

Answer (score -3):

This explanation is what i think about it and i have no reference for this.

**Here you go**:

This doesn't mean 'I give it to you'.

Consider you've asked for the Phone i have. I give it to you saying 'Here you go'. The giving is done in action so it is not necessarily be said in words.

Instead you asked it for doing something and i say 'Here you get it to do the thing you wanted' Get going.

Similarly, **Here you are** ready for the task(to do with the thing you asked).

Comment: I do not understand this answer. Can you clarify?